# Vue.js builder produces incorrect paths in index.html

Tags: javascript, vue.js

The problem is that after building vue app in destination folder there is index.html with incorrect paths to static assets. Links look like

```
<link href="/static/js/chunk-29e00bf1.49e28fbb.js" rel="prefetch">
```

which is incorrect, but should be

```
<link href="static/js/chunk-29e00bf1.49e28fbb.js" rel="prefetch">
```

And browser look into ///D:/static/js/ instead of D://.../build/dist/static/js .

There is my vue.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  outputDir: './build/dist/',
  assetsDir: './static', //...
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `publicPath` property, and set the path to `./` to use relative paths on build.

```js
module.exports = {
    ...
    publicPath: "./"
    ...
}
```

Read more in the official documentation: [publicPath](https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#publicpath)